# How to implement tab-like menu in all pages in application, without writing the same code over and over again

Tags: inheritance, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I want a menu in my application that persists across pages. One way to achieve that is to declare the menu layout and eventhandlers in every page of the application, but that would be bad practice.

I have tried to implement a page that declares the menu and eventhandlers and then have all other inheriting from it, like the example below from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/6c30d7e5-741f-4ce7-8306-72cae73d7ff4, but it seems that it won't work for eventhandlers. Does anyone have experience with this or know of other approaches that work better?

```
<InheritedPage:PhoneApplicationPageDerived 
    x:Class="InheritedPage.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:InheritedPage="clr-namespace:InheritedPage;assembly=InheritedPage"
    xmlns:phoneNavigation="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Navigation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitleGrid is the name of the application and page title-->
        <Grid x:Name="TitleGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="textBlockPageTitle" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextPageTitle1Style}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page title" x:Name="textBlockListTitle" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextPageTitle2Style}"/>
        </Grid>

        <!--ContentGrid is empty. Place new content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="Virtual" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="SomeVirtualMethod" />
            <Button Content="Base" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="320,0,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="SomeBaseMethod" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</InheritedPage:PhoneApplicationPageDerived>





using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace InheritedPage {

    public class PhoneApplicationPageBase : PhoneApplicationPage {

        public PhoneApplicationPageBase() {
        }

        public virtual void SomeVirtualMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine("PhoneApplicationPageBase Virtual Method");
        }

    }

    public class PhoneApplicationPageDerived : PhoneApplicationPageBase {

        public PhoneApplicationPageDerived() {
        }

        public override void SomeVirtualMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine("PhoneApplicationPageDerived Override Method");
        }

    }

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPageDerived {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();

            SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait | SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
        }


        // 1. COMMENT OUT THIS METHOD DECLARATION to see virtual inherited methods 
        // break Application.LoadComponent in the generated MainPage.g.cs

        public override void SomeVirtualMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine("MainPage Override Method");
        }


        // 2. MOVE THIS METHOD DECLARATION into PhoneApplicationPageBase to see non virtual inherited 
        // methods break Application.LoadComponent in the generated MainPage.g.cs

        public void SomeBaseMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            Debug.WriteLine("PhoneApplicationPageBase Base Method");
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when inventing really custom UI in Silverlight...Microsoft is very picky about the look and feel of Silverlight apps.  They're obviously much more forgiving of XNA apps.

To answer your question, my approach would be to declare a static class that contains the menu items in the persisted menu, then create a custom control for your menu that populates itself by accessing that static data.  Then simply add one of these controls to every page where you want it persisted.

I have a feeling this would get kicked back by MS, but you can definitely give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you, that is a really interesting perspective on the problem. Can you think of any way of achieving the 'global' menu functionality that would be in line with MS WP7 UI guidelines?

Comment: Possibly...if it's small enough it might persist across multiple pages of a panorama.  But as far as just willy-nilly navigation having a menu that persists, I'm guessing they would say it violates the spirit of the WP7 experience.